# Google Sign-In Access Token between backend and client

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, backend, google-signin

For a quick project for a hack week me and my team implemented Google Sign-In as registration/authentication for users. The way it works:

1. User signs in with SDK on client (Android + iOS) and requests access_token
2. Client receives acces_token and uses that token for each network request to the backend as a query parameter
3. Our backend does not interact with google services on users behalf

The problem I'm facing is that the provided access_token returned by the google SDK is short-lived (60 minutes). That basically leads me to two questions/problems:

1. Is the short-living access_token even meant to be used that way?
   I am used to another flow where you just use that returned token by google or any other auth provider to authenticate with your backend and then use your own authentication mechanism (probably token based as well).
2. If I am wrong about 1. then what is a good practise to refresh the token on the client side as it expires every 60 minutes. The way I understand it is that Google SDK starts an activity for result to sign in and I would rather want to handle all the networking in my data layer without context. Do I check the validity of that token before I request the backend every time or do I start some kind of refreshing after I get a 401 response back or something similar?

I am somewhat new in that space and I had quite some discussion about what is right and wrong with the backend guy in our team. I'm thinking number one is right, he says number two. I might be terribly wrong here. Some nice input or resources would be awesome as all the documentation online just don't answer both of those questions.

Comment: Good question. Does your app support any other user authentication mechanisms (Facebook, username/password, etc.), or just Google? If multiple auth methods, most developers, use option 1 and exchange the password/Facebook/Google token for their own session management mechanism (cookie or their own OAuth2 tokens, typically). But if you only have Google, then you could simply get an ID token from the SDK whenever you need to make an authenticated backend request and attach it as authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing use your google provided access token to generate a new access token in your backend and send this token on login/signup to client. Now your every request will use this token to identify users and keep track of everything. 
This will not expire too. I used this in my app and it works flawlessly.